# Which layer should i place .edmx and generated POCO classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, domain-driven-design

This is regarding a layered design with EF DB First model.

So far i have not used Entity Framework before, used only Entities and placed on a different project with Domain/ DTO sub folders. Also referred the same in DataAccessLayer, Business Layer and MVC application and written a code with usual ADO.Net queries and prepared POCOs of my entities. No issues.

Now we are **developing an application using Entity Framework DB First model**. We choosen this DB First model, as the DB Design is not in our control. It is done by DBA.

I thought of reusing the old simple design here. But not sure where/which layer I should exactly fit the edmx file and the generated POCO classes. I didn't find any samples with layered architecture style uses DBFirst approach.

I referred this. http://aspnetdesignpatterns.codeplex.com But they use NHybernate

Here is the highlevel overview of old design.[image]

Any suggestions on design/samples, please you are welcome.

**Edit:**

***From the below answer, I think the entity framework produces the POCOs we could rename existing Entities/Domain layer to Domain Layer and putting the generated POCO classes there. Also we can simply keep .edmx in DataAccessLayer with the list of IRepository classes that wraps EF for TDD. Does this makes sence? or any valuable points?***

**Update:**

> Currently i removed DataAccessLayer and keep only Entities layer which
>   has a model.edmx file and classes generated by EF and also all
>   Repository classes implementing IRepository. I refer this into
>   Business Layer, MVC as well. Am i doing right? I feel like i am doing
>   a bad design :( Please suggest/help

Comment: The image is useless: it does not show how the layers refer to one another.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're unfortunately severely handicapped by the decision to create the database first, you will need to use an [Anti-Corruption layer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnticorruptionLayer) per [Eric Evans' Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

This is a good solution for what to do when you're given a shitty interface that you absolutely must code against - make an interface wrapped around the DB that behaves the way you want it to.  Do not expose any EF classes directly to anything except the anti-corruption layer itself.

Here's a reading example:

```
public class SomeReadService : ISomeReadService {
  public SomeViewModel Load(Guid id) {
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext()) {
      // Query the DB model, then *map* the EF classes to SomeVieWModel.
      // This way you are not exposing the shitty DB model to the outside world.
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a writing example:

```
public class SomeRepository : ISomeRepository {
  public SomeDomainObject Load(Guid id) {
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext()) {
      // Map the EF classes to your domain object.  Same idea as before.
    }
  }
}
```

I would still try to demonstrate to the client that having a separate team design the DB will be a disaster (and my experience strongly indicates that it will).  See if there is some way you can provide the feedback that will demonstrate to the client that it would be better if you designed the DB.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you please provide some sample code/template for design using DBFirst approach. Client is not agreed to take a DB Design control at our end. They asked us to follow DBA people :(. Currently i removed DataAccessLayer and keep only Entities which has a model.edmx file and classes generated by EF. I refer this into Business Layer, MVC as well. Am i following right? I kept IRepository implementing classes into Entities layer itself. I feel like i am doing a bad design :( Please suggest

Comment: I would still recommend you put your foot down and simply refuse to do the project under those terms.  If you want to be successful in this business, there are projects you need to walk away from if they don't stand a good chance of being successful.  This may well be one of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the SO link for similar kind of question below:

[With a database-first approach, how do I separate my Core and Infrastructure layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666999/with-a-database-first-approach-how-do-i-separate-my-core-and-infrastructure-lay)

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Entity Framework used correctly negates the need for a seperate DAL. I think of EF as my DAL. It allows you to concentrate on the business part more. EF does all the data access code for you. You can simply use your EF context in your business layer. To me, this is one of the best benefits of EF; that it is your DAL.

Depending on how you separate your layers (different assemblies or different folders within an assembly) depends where you put your POCO classes. If different assemblies (which is overkill for most projects) then a 'Common' assembly referenced by all others is the place to put POCO classes. If different folders, then a folder named 'Models' or 'DomainModels' is the place.

Specifically for an MVC application, I would put my POCO classes in the 'Models' folder (I also have a 'ViewModels' folder), and my .Edmx in a BLL folder which I sometimes call 'Logic'.

If you need a loosely coupled architecture for testing, then a folder named Repositories with the EF context wrapped in your own repository pattern is the way to go.

Comment: If we dont add any wrapper to EF how do we test it alone? I need a loosely coupled architecture and highly testable.

Comment: Wrap context in your repo pattern, and place it in a folder called repositories where the bll is.

Comment: Is this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080339/n-tier-architecture-with-service-layer-business-layer-and-entity-framework?rq=1

Comment: Yes, you will need a concrete implementation of your IRepository for each table in your context. A full tutorial of how to do that is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309753/Repository-Pattern-with-Entity-Framework-4-1-and-C

Comment: So basically my DAL will be a list of Repository Concrete Class implements IRepository<T>. The way they used in http://aspnetdesignpatterns.codeplex.com for NHybernet, just browse source code section. But how about the POCOs generated by EDMX file, i mean Domain Objects. Where i keep it? These needs to be shared across application layers like presentation, business and repository.

Comment: Try not to over think it too much. If layers are in separate assemblies, your edmx will need to go in a 'Common' assembly that has no dependencies (except EF). Inside of your BLL you will need a folder called Repositories that has a concrete implementation of each IRepo. You could separate this out to another assembly, but personally I prefer to keep the number of assemblies down to a minimum. Does that make sense?

Comment: of topic but I have to disagree with you about the best benefit of EF: because of the fact that EF needs access to your class you have to expose your class with public auto properties and a paramless constructor. Some even say that because of this you still need a DAL and a Automapper with DTO classes to protect the Domain

Comment: I see where your coming from, but my feeling is that is overkill nearly always. EF is easy to swap out, especially if it is wrapped by the repo pattern. Duplicating classes for both DA and Domain is more work and takes more time to understand the project to newcomers. If the project is worked on by multiple teams then complete separation of DAL is good. If less than 5 people I don't think the overhead is worth it.

Comment: Changed to "one of the best" benefits.

Comment: "With Entity Framework used correctly a DAL layer is no longer necessary" => disagree. You still need to separate the Domain layer from the Persistence layer. Your Domain should be Entity Framework-agnostic. Entity Framework Repository implementations should be in the Infrastructure (Persistence) layer.

Comment: @guillaume31 so how would you separate these concerns? and what advantages do you get from your way? Another answer to the opening question would be beneficial.

Comment: As far as DDD is concerned, "EF used correctly" is IMO Code First, not Database First, and it doesn't negate the need for a separate DAL, quite the contrary - it *enables* you to have a clear separation between Domain layer and DAL. The benefits of persistence ignorance are : you can take your Domain dll and reuse it elsewhere without dragging along EF-specific stuff, you can test your layers in isolation, less coupling means improved maintainability, etc.

Comment: I don't have an answer that would satisfy the DB-first prerequisite and still be DDD compatible (they are antithetic IMO) - I was just reacting to your assertion.

Comment: I agree Code First is the way forward. And partly with the rest. Everything I have done so far has never required the domain assembly to be used elsewhere, even though we always separate it off at work. At home I don't bother and feel it is not worth the effort.

Comment: My assertion was meant to be closer to a rule of thumb.

Comment: @guillaume31 In my case what should i do. I do understand  and like doing with CodeFirst. But unfortunately this decision was made by client team and DB team they have. Now i should take care of writing loosely coupled code. Help me on how can i arrange my layers and classes here

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The Short Answer is **Data Access Layer (DAL)**

You need to **Enterprise architecture** and it changes according your needs, but in your case **Model Driving Design Pattern** is the solid solution.
You can use **MVC** and you can drive your model from **Poco** or other entities like **NHibernet** etc.

No any importance **about code-first** or **db-first**, it is interesting just with the architecture creation phase.